# Initialization of array based on vector size in structure [c++]

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I'm trying to create a program that split a region into subsets (8 here), and each subset contains 8 values (corresponding to predefined vectors).
I defined a structure to store these values (as well as vectors):

```
struct Storage {
  static const int num_spatial_subset = 8;
  static const std::vector< std::vector<double> > vectors = 
    { {0,0,0}, 
      {0,1,0}, 
      {0,0,1}, 
      {1,1,0}, 
      {1,0,1}, 
      {0,1,1}, 
      {1,0,0}, 
      {1,1,1} };
  double storage[num_spatial_subset][vectors.size()];
};
```

However, I'm getting a compilation error at 'vectors' intialization:

```
 error: field initializer is not constant
       {1,1,1} };
               ^
 error: in-class initialization of static data member ‘const std::vector<std::vector<double> > Storage::vectors’ of non-literal type
 error: non-constant in-class initialization invalid for static member ‘Storage::vectors’
 error: (an out of class initialization is required)
 error: ‘Storage::vectors’ cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression when being declared
 error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
   double storage[num_spatial_subset][vectors.size()];
```

vectors will be the same for all Storage object (which is why I defined them as static const).

I know that I could replace my storage variable with a vector and resize it in the constructor of Storage, but that will involve to resize the first vector to 8, and loop to resize all inside vectors to 8 too.
As I might have to create thousands of these objects, I don't think it's the optimal way to do it.

I don't really understand why compiler complains, because vectors are defined at compile time (as well as the number of vectors).

Thank you.

Comment: Off topic: Do you really need a `vector` here? If it isn't going to change in size at runtime, `static const double vectors[][3];` will have a bit less overhead and be contiguous in memory.

Comment: If the size is constant, maybe you should consider using `std::array` instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: The problem with std::array is that you have to specify the dimension when you create it (and modify it when you add new data). This could be a possible solution, but I would prefer to have a 'transparent dimension', defined only by the number of vectors in it, so I can easily add a new vector to the list without having to be careful about also modifying the data. If I was the only one to use the code, I might have done that, but as other people may modify it, I would like to make it 'simple' to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `size` on a `vector` can never return a constant because it doesn't meet the C++ rules for a constant. The compiler is not required to know what `size()` does, and for all it knows, it returns the time since the program started executing. If you know the value is constant, then you can define a constant that holds that value. But the compiler is not required to have the knowledge to do that for you.

Even if the compiler did somehow know that the value was constant, it would be doing you a disservice by allowing you to write code like that. What happens when the next version of the library or the compiler, or some other compiler, doesn't know that?

Comment: That's a good point. However, even by replacing double storage[num_spatial_subset][vectors.size()] by double storage[8][8], I still have the field initializer is not constant error.
Also adding a value to store the number of vector defeat a bit the purpose of it. For example, if I add a new vector and forget to change the number, then I can quickly find myself with a segfault, because the storage variable won't have the proper size.

Comment: He does exactly what I suggest you do. Don't use `size` and instead substitute the numerical constant (the `[3]` in his code). He didn't explain what was wrong with your code or the logic behind his fix.

Comment: Not the second issue (scaling the storage variable with the number of vectors)

Answer (score 1):

> error: (an out of class initialization is required)

so just do

```
struct Storage {
  static const int num_spatial_subset = 8;
  static const std::vector< std::vector<double> > vectors;
  double storage[num_spatial_subset][3];
};

const std::vector< std::vector<double> > Storage::vectors = 
    { {0,0,0}, 
      {0,1,0}, 
      {0,0,1}, 
      {1,1,0}, 
      {1,0,1}, 
      {0,1,1}, 
      {1,0,0}, 
      {1,1,1} };
```

As alternative, you may use `initializer_list`

```
struct Storage {
  static const int num_spatial_subset = 8;
  static constexpr std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<double>> vectors{ {0,0,0}, 
      {0,1,0}, 
      {0,0,1}, 
      {1,1,0}, 
      {1,0,1}, 
      {0,1,1}, 
      {1,0,0}, 
      {1,1,1} };
  double storage[num_spatial_subset][vectors.size()];
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/018ea029d0aa77fb)

Comment: double storage[num_spatial_subset][3] should be  double storage[num_spatial_subset][8], because I have 8 vectors in 'vectors'. But the problem is that if I have another vector to 'vectors' and I (or someone else) forget to modify double storage[num_spatial_subset][8] to  double storage[num_spatial_subset][9], then this could create segfault.
I'd like my storage variable to scale with the number of vectors (which are hard coded = defined at compile time).

Comment: @whiteShadow: initializer_list is an alternative.

Comment: I'm still getting 'error: field initializer is not constant' with initializer_list

Comment: I copy/paste your code, and I get the same error (field initialized is not constant). I saw on your demo you compiled with -std=c++14. I use -std=c++11, I also tried with -std=c++1y (I run g++ 4.8.4) but I still get the error.

Comment: I just realized that coliru is running gcc 6.1.0 while I'm running gcc 4.8.4. I guess this is why you're code is not compiling on my computer but does on coliru.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like `vectors` is not intended to be resized at run time, I pitch discarding the `vector`s and going with a static 2D array.

Edit:

The simple solution is to remove `vectors` from the class so that it can be fully defined before the size is required.

```
const double vectors[][3] =
{
    { 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 1 }
    // add more here and storage will resize
};
```

We cannot get the number of rows in an array from an array, so we need to do a bit of work to get the size of `Storage::storage`. We can't get rows, but we can get the size of the whole array (`sizeof(vectors)` or 8*3 *sizeof(double) = 192 in the current example) at compile time and the size of a row in the array (`sizeof(vectors[0])` or 3 *sizeof(double) or 24). Dividing total size by row size will give us the number of rows (192 / 24 = 8).

```
struct Storage
{
    static const int num_spatial_subset = 8;
    // can't get the number of rows, but we can get the total size and divide 
    // it by the size of a row. 
    double storage[num_spatial_subset][sizeof(vectors) / sizeof(vectors[0])];
};
```

If vectors must be contained within `Storage`, we need to abstract in order to define the size of `vectors` before it is needed:

```
struct BaseStorage
{
    static const double vectors[][3];
};
const double BaseStorage::vectors[][3] =
{
    { 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 1 }
    // add more here and storage will resize
};

struct Storage: public BaseStorage
{
    static const int num_spatial_subset = 8;
    double storage[num_spatial_subset][sizeof(vectors) / sizeof(vectors[0])];
};
```

Comment: Is it clean to do : sizeof(vectors) / sizeof(vectors[0]) ?

Comment: It would have worked if I wasn't stupid. Deleting answer in a few minutes if I can't salvage it.

Comment: @whiteShadow Salvaged it

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. However, I'm surprised how tricky it is to do something quite simple (everything is defined at compile time).